# Liferay homepage is not found after starting the server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

I have set up a Liferay Tomcat Server in Eclipse. After the server starts and I go to localhost:8181 (where I configured the server), the page is empty. Also, if I right click the server in Eclipse and select Open Liferay Portal Home, a 404 Page Not Found is displayed.

When I start the server outside Eclipse, with startup.bat, the page loads just fine.

Does anyone have a clue about why this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using Liferay IDE in Eclipse. It might be accurate even if you're not.

Try making your edits in the Eclipse workspace's server.xml file. The workspace should have a Servers folder, with your Tomcat Liferay server underneath it. The path in my workspace is as follows:

```
eclipse-luna-workspace/Servers/Liferay v6.2 CE Server (Tomcat 7) at localhost-config
```

Underneath the directory for the server are copies of the Tomcat configuration files, including server.xml. Make your edits to this server.xml file, restart your server in Eclipse, and Eclipse should copy it to the Tomcat instance at startup.

Comment: When you use Liferay IDE you can just double click the server name in the server view and edit its properties there - no need to mess around with server.xml. Especially with regards to the ports, this works quite well. Memory setup and others as well

Answer (score 0):

Where you defined Tomcat http port? And in which way Tomcat is configured in Eclipse?
These questions because Eclipse is able (but it's not mandatory) to override Tomcat default configurations.

Just a note: do you try to use Liferay plugin for Eclipse? It can help you to proper configure a Liferay server in Eclipse (and help you for development also).